# How can I hand out free copies of my otherwise-paid Play Store game?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

With Google Play Services, is it possible to give people redeemable codes for an Android game I made, or give them special access or something like that? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Quora post revealed itself after a quick google search. It seems to address the question you are asking. In short, you can add the users as "Testers" for your development account and this will enable them to download the app for free.

The question:

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-distribute-a-paid-Android-app-for-free-to-press-or-reviewers-If-so-how

The answer I found:

http://qr.ae/R4D1CC